# How can I delete the name of figure?

Tags: graphics, floats

First I use `\usepackage{graphicx}`

Then I use this command to insert the figure `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Close Price.png}`.

But finally I get the name of it, which is "Price.png".
I do not know where it come from, how can I delete this name and set a new name of it?
The latex shows like below pic.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Not using spaces in file names is the recommended approach, but you could also enclode the file name in quotes. So `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{"Close Price.png"}` should also work.  Also, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that reproduces the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting bug (I got the same result with TeX Live 2017), but there is an easy workaround: rename your image file without spaces. For example `ClosePrice.png`.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I rename this figure to the other name, for example "figure 1"?

Comment: Maybe you mean figure captions? Please see [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Captioning_Figures) or [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) etc.